# apkanalyzer throws NoClassDefFoundError on debug apk

Tags: android, apk

apkanalyzer throws NoClassDefFoundError on debug apk, in a Mac machine

Android Installation

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
```

Machine Information

```
uname -a
Darwin user.local 22.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 20:59:58 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T6020 arm64
```

APK Analyzer failure

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/apkanalyzer app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli.getAaptInvokerFromSdk(ApkAnalyzerCli.java:277)
    at com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli.main(ApkAnalyzerCli.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
    ... 5 more
```